# return multiple values in different cells in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Function toto() As Variant

    For Each cell In Range("N1:N45")
        found = 0
        For Each cell2 In Range("B:B")
            If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                found = 1
            End If
            If found = 1 Then
                toto = cell.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
     Next    
End Function
```

I want to return multiple values in excel.
how should i change that?

Comment: Probably an array.  What precisely do you want returned?  Just values, or values with cell locations, or value-here and value-there, or what?

Comment: @Smandoli i would like to return multiple cell values in excel (one for each)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a global variable to count the number of matches found.  Declare this variable at the top of your code and modify your function like this:

```
Dim found As Integer

Function toto() As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    For Each cell In Range("N1:N45")
        For Each cell2 In Range("B:B")
            If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                count = count + 1

                'Skip over previously returned values
                If count > found Then
                    found = found + 1
                    toto = cell.Value
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
     Next
End Function
```

---

The global variable will retain it's value even when the function is not in use.  This means that each time you call the `toto()` function it will skip past the previously found value.  This also means that you have to reset if if you want to start over.

Here is a test sub.  The first call will find the first match.  The second call will find the second match because we didn't reset `found` to zero between calls.

```
Sub test()
    'Reset function
    found = 0
    MsgBox (toto())

    MsgBox (toto())
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvote for interesting, clever and astute.  Curious if this will meet the need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Function toto() As Variant
    For Each cell In Range("N1:N45")
        found = 0
        For Each cell2 In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:B"))
            If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                found = 1
            End If
            If found = 1 Then
                toto = toto & ", " & cell.Value
                found = 0
            End If
        Next
     Next
End Function
```

Comment: There are things to like in this answer.  However, the `found` variable seems unnecessary (which means the function can be 3-4 lines shorter); more important, in my experience a concatenated string is not such a useful result.  But maybe it is just what the user wants.

Comment: @Smandoli:  I agree with you completely......... **found** is not necessary..........what I don't like about the function is that it lack arguments..........volatility issues may arise..........

Answer (score 0):

```
Function foo()
        y = 3
        For Each cell In Range("B2:B64")
            found = 0
            For Each cell2 In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
                If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                    found = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If found = 0 Then
                y = y + 1
                Cells(y, "D").Value = cell.Value
            End If
         Next   
End Function
```

And then had a Sub function to call foo

```
Sub foo2()
    Range("D4:D80").ClearContents
    toto
End Sub
```